# No Internet after upgrading to 12.10

Tags: networking, upgrade, macbook

I upgraded to Quantic yesterday; it runs on a Macbook Pro.
After using boot-repair to be able to boot to Ubuntu (via live CD), I found myself without any connection to Internet, be it with ethernet or wireless.

When I try a `ping ubuntu.com` from the default Ubuntu terminal, the only answer I get is `ping: unknown host ubuntu.com`.

Here is a list of facts:

- The computer is a macbook pro ("MacBookPro3,1" with `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name`);
- Internet is provided through a router (with Tomato on it);
- Local network works fine: I can ping other devices, mount NAS volumes via fstab, etc.
- Other devices can connect to Internet; this is how I can write this question.
- I searched on askubuntu.com and other websites, but everything I tried end up with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Here is what a `lspci -nnk` gives me:

```
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 PCI Express Root Port [8086:2a01] (rev 03)
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2834] (rev 03)
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2835] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:283a] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:284b] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:283f] (rev 03)
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 [8086:2843] (rev 03)
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2847] (rev 03)
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:2849] (rev 03)
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2830] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2831] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2832] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:2836] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2815] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller [8086:2850] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:2828] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:283e] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel modules: i2c-i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G84 [GeForce 8600M GT] [10de:0407] (rev a1)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00a0]
  Kernel driver in use: nvidia
  Kernel modules: nvidia_current, nouveau, nvidiafb
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5418 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5008E 802.11(a)bgn] (PCI-Express) [168c:0024] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. AR5BXB72 802.11abgn Mini PCIe Card [AR5008E-3NX] [106b:0087]
  Kernel driver in use: ath9k
  Kernel modules: ath9k
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:436a] (rev 13)
  Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Imac 8,1 Wired Ethernet Adapter [11ab:00ba]
  Kernel driver in use: sky2
  Kernel modules: sky2
0d:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Texas Instruments TSB82AA2 IEEE-1394b Link Layer Controller [104c:8025] (rev 02)
  Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
  Kernel modules: firewire-ohci
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and resolved it by disabling dnsmask. Run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

And comment the `dns=dnsmaaq` line appearing in:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq
```

Comment it out by writing `#` before it:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Then, to apply your changes, reboot or restart networking.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found my way around the problem. I don't know if this is the right thing to do, but it worked for me. Here's what I did, based on the informations found at [Network Configuration > Dynamic IP Address Assignment (DHCP Client)](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html):

I opened "/etc/network/interfaces" with vi:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

The actual state was of the file was:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I changed it to dhcp because I'm using a router as DHCP server:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I also restarted the "networking" service with:

```
sudo restart networking
```

Then I had Internet back. :)

I don't exactly know why this file would have changed while upgrading to 12.10. Maybe some other logic has changed and this was a side effect; I can't tell.
You can try this out first if you encounter a similar problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue:

[Launchpad bug#1051348](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1051348)